# How to make the React native web view support a camera and self signed certificate from local server?

Tags: react-native, ssl-certificate, react-native-webview

Let say I have a web application with a camera library [Instrascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan) running on my local server + HTTPS (use a self-signed certificate).

I would like to make the ReactNative WebView to run the web app from my local server and now the problem I'm facing is the Instascan lib tries to call `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` function to get media devices e.g. Camera and Microphone (with HTTP the result of `enumerateDevices()` is always an empty array)

so when the ReactNative WebView open my app from my local server (URL=https://192.168.1.200:9999) I got an error below:

```js
{"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "code": 3, "description": "SSL error: The certificate authority is not trusted", "loading": false, "target": 9, "title": "", "url": "https://192.168.1.200:9999"}
```

I have added a network_security_config to `android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```xml
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application ... android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
      ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

this is my [react-native webview component](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)

```js
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://192.168.1.200:9999' }}
  javaScriptEnabled
  allowsInlineMediaPlayback
  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  useWebKit
  startInLoadingState
  scalesPageToFit
  onError={syntheticEvent => {
    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
    console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
  }}
/>
```

here are my dependencies:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10"
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1"
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.1"
"prop-types": "^15.7.2"
"react": "16.13.1"
"react-native": "0.63.2"
"react-native-camera": "^3.35.0"
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0"
"react-native-permissions": "^2.1.5"
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.1"
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1"
"react-native-screens": "^2.9.0"
"react-native-webview": "^10.3.2"
```

to summarize my problem now I'm facing these 2 problems:

1. the problem of `SSL error: The certificate authority is not trusted` when using a self-signed certificate.
2. When I tried some web app for camera testing below the camera seem to work but it cannot stream an images. it only shows a static image of the first image while initialize the camera.

- https://turncameraon.com/
- https://webcamtests.com/
- https://marcusbelcher.github.io/wasm-asm-camera-webgl-test/index.html

Please anybody give me some advices?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever get this to run?

Comment: no, not yet. I just ignored it for now

Comment: I've the SSL error because I need to access into a testing web with invalid certificate (that I can't to change). I'm looking how to avoid or jump this error.